"Permettere qualcuno (di fare qualcosa)" or "Permettere a qualcuno (di fare qualcosa)"?
What's the difference between "Permettere qualcuno (di fare qualcosa)" or "Permettere a qualcuno (di fare qualcosa)?"
For example:

Ho permesso mio marito di andare in vacanza da solo.
Ho permesso a mio marito di andare in vacanza da solo.


It's permettere a qualcuno di fare qualcosa, as you can see in these examples from the book Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri (Loescher Editore, Torino, 2013):


Mia madre non permetteva a noi figlie di tenere i capelli lunghi.
Per la laurea hanno regalato a Paolo una moto ma non gli permettono di guidarla


In the second example you can see how the indirect object pronoun gli is used to convey a Paolo.

Exactly. Let me write it down explicitly: *“permettere qualcuno (di fare qualcosa)” is not Italian.
